# Installing OpenJDK 8 (subversion 1.8.0.119) for Mac using Homebrew?

Tags: java, java-8, homebrew

I want to install OpenJDK 8 version 1.8.0.119 on my Mac using Homebrew. What is the brew command to specify the version while installing?

I am able to install OpenJDK using the brew command `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`, but the version installed (1.8.0.212) is later than the one I want.

Comment: Question: why do you want to install a specific point release? Normally people usually want the latest point release, to pick up bug fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulae in Homebrew core and the AdoptOpenJDK tap only support the latest versions of a given major release. If you need to install a particular minor version or point release, you will need to create your own custom formula in a [custom tap you maintain](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.md).

Start with one of the existing formulae for the major release you want. Copy it to your custom formula, and include the version in your new formula name. Edit the formula to point at the download URL for the particular version you want, and fix up the `sha256` checksum value.

Answer (score 0):

From [AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk github](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/blob/master/Casks/adoptopenjdk8.rb), we can see it only support install fixed version, for jdk8, it is 1.8.0.212.

The oldest version for jdk8 on [AdoptOpenJDK website](https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk8) is 1.8.0.172.